# Issue in changing package name of two modules in android

Tags: java, android

[image]

I have the two modules in my project one `services` and another is `products`. The problem is both these modules have same package name that is `com.example.services`. When I am trying to change the package name of one of them by refactor change package name. Then package name of both modules changes in my project. Please help me.

Comment: I suppose you want to only change one package's name? Create the package structure manually, move the class to that package.

Comment: I want to change the peckage name of Products to com.example.product when i do so the peckage of the Services also changed.

Comment: As I said: create the package manually, move the class to the package.

Comment: As @Turing85 says, you need to create the package manually. Probably, you'll find it easier if you change your `Project -> Android` to `Project-> Project` . From the Project toolbar at the top left of Android Studio.

Comment: Ok, I create the peckage and shift the classes to it. will i create two another peckages because i have aslo in androidTest and test directory

Comment: As an aside: this is not really a `java`- or `android`-question, but an `intellij`-question.